# Calculate date range using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetimepicker, date-range

I use a date/time picker to select date and time:

```
var d = new Date();

$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
    separator: '@',
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(),
});
```

minDate and maxDate define the date range. No dates in the past should be selected, so the current date is the lower bound.

The upper bound should be max 2 month in the future. So how do I handle that when current month is 11? Any ideas on a function that calculates date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date(); // initially contains current date
var e = new Date(); // initially contains current date
                    // note: both dates must initially contain same value
e.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2);
console.log(d);    
console.log(e);
```

Replace `console.log` with `alert` if necessary. This will work for dates in November and December in case you're wondering.

Comment: will that switch year when d.getMonth() is eg. 11?

Comment: Quote: *This will work for dates in November and December in case you're wondering*. Yes it will work just the way you expect. I encourage you to verify this by initializing both dates as `new Date("11/01/2010")` and verify the result -> `01/01/2011`.